# Memory leaks observed when navigating through Android Jetpack Compose Bottom Navigation with Hilt ViewModel

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt

I'm currently working on an Android application that has bottom navigation and screens with `viewmodels` that has been injected by `HiltViewModel`.

The problem is when I select another bottom navigation item, previous screen refuses be destroyed.

**Simplified example:**

ViewModels:

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class Screen1ViewModel @Inject constructor(
    //...
) : ViewModel() {
    //...
}

@HiltViewModel
class Screen2ViewModel @Inject constructor(
    //...
) : ViewModel() {
    //...
}
```

Screens:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Screen1(
    viewModel: Screen1ViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    //...
}

@Composable
fun Screen2(
    viewModel: Screen2ViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    //...
    val lifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current
    LaunchedEffect(lifecycleOwner) {
        lifecycleOwner.lifecycle.addObserver(
            LifecycleEventObserver { source, event ->
                println(event)
            }
        )
    }
    //...
}
```

And a custom bottom navigation that invokes `onSelectionChanged` when I select a bottom navigation item.

```kotlin
CustomBottomNavigation(
    //...
    onSelectionChanged = {
        val destination = when (it) {
            0 -> "screen1"
            1 -> "screen2"
        }
       navController.navigate(destination)
    }
)
```

When I open app it starts with `Screen1` then I choose `Screen2` using bottom navigation. output is:

```
ON_CREATE
ON_START
ON_RESUME
```

Then I choose `Screen1` using bottom navigation, output is:

```
ON_PAUSE
ON_STOP
```

It does not print 'ON_DESTROY', so `viewmodel` cannot be destroyed and when I select `Screen2` again, it creates another instance of `viewmodel` and previous instance leakes.

I would be grateful for any help

Comment: Does your ViewModel get a call to `onCleared`?

Comment: @ianhanniballake No, `viewmodel` does not invoke `onCleared`

Comment: Your `CustomBottomNavigation` is just calling `navigate` - that's just going to add a new screen to your back stack over and over and over again. Does you back button take you back through each and every separate instance you created? Is that the behavior you want? Why aren't you using the same [navigate logic as the documentation shows](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#bottom-nav)?

Comment: @ianhanniballake Actually this code is simplified, In my real code I used jetpack compose `BackHandler` in same place with `Navhost` to avoid pressing back. the main problem is when I use back button in each sub pages (Sub page of Screen 2), `viewmodel` get destroyed but when I use bottom navigation to get back. `viewmodel` leaks. one thing I forgot to say is when I want to navigate through bottom navigation, I pop up to start destination to avoid any duplicate instances.

Comment: Sounds like you are doing everything wrong then. What happens when you remove your `BackHandler` and actually let the `NavHost` handle back as you should? Do you actually get multiple instances?

Comment: @ianhanniballake No, each time I select bottom nav item, I clear back stack. Actually `BackHandler` can be removed.